# Spectrogram of an Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, spectrogram

I have a 2048x2048 image and as part of processing it, I am trying to identify frequencies through spectrogram but I think it works only per row or column of the image and not on a batch of rows. Am I wrong? can someone help with implementing the Spectrogram function on an image?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fast Fourier Transforms to create 2-D spectra are available as part of the  [SciPy FFT package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fftpack.html)

Comment: @John1024Thank you for your comment. I know the function 'fftn' but I am trying to find a matlab function for the spectrogram (for image) instead of writing it from scratch.

Comment: @John1024 
Thank you for your comment. I know the function 'fftn' but I am trying to find a matlab function for the spectrogram (for image) instead of writing it from scratch.

Comment: I am not a Matlab user but have you looked at [MathWorks 2-D fast Fourier transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)?